# Avoiding global variables in Perl (What is the "right" way?)

Tags: perl, variables, global-variables, code-organization, scoping

When writing Perl code I frequently run into the situation where I have a large cluster of variables at the top of the file that act as "global" variables within the script.  I have been writing these "global" variables in all capital letters to differentiate them from others, but I have recently been working on some very large scripts with many modules and would really like to learn a good way to minimize the use of "global" variables and make my code as safe as possible.

The situation I run into frequently is having two subroutines that share a large number of variables:

```
my $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 . . .
sub sub1 {
    # uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
    # may even make changes to some of these variables
}

sub sub2 {
    # also uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
    # may change $var1, $var2, $var3
}

sub sub3 {
    # doesn't use $var1, $var2, $var3
    # still has access to change them
}
```

passing all of these variables into each subroutine and returning 4 or 5 variables can look very ugly and can quickly get difficult to keep track of all of the variables, but if I keep these variables global I run into the issue of sub3 potentially editing them when it shouldn't.

I know I can scope variables using "{}" to do this, but in my personal opinion i think this looks quite ugly:

```
{
    my $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 . . .
    sub sub1 {
        # uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
        # may even make changes to some of these variables
    }

    sub sub2 {
        # also uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
        # may change $var1, $var2, $var3
    }
}

sub sub3 {
    # doesn't use $var1, $var2, $var3
    # no longer has access to change them
}
```

Also if I use "{}" to scope variables what happens if sub1 and sub2 share variables that they don't want sub3 to have access to, and then I also want sub1 and sub3 to share variables that sub2 won't have access to?  Using "{}" to scope the variables that doesn't seem to be possible.  An attempt to do that would look something like this:

```
{
    my $varx, $vary, $varz . . .
    {
        my $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5 . . .
        sub sub1 {
            # uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
            # may change $var1, $var2, $var3

            # uses $varx, $vary, $varz . . .
            # may change $varx, $vary, $varz
        }
    
        sub sub2 {
            # also uses $var1, $var2, $var3 . . .
            # may change $var1, $var2, $var3

            # does not use $varx, $vary, $varz . . .
            ############################################
            # still able to change $varx, $vary, $varz #
            ############################################
        }
    }
    
    sub sub3 {
        # doesn't use $var1, $var2, $var3
        # no longer has access to change them

        # uses $varx, $vary, $varz . . .
        # may change $varx, $vary, $varz
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to restrict access other than using "{}"?  Even if the only solution is to get into object oriented Perl feel free to throw out some ideas (If you do go into object oriented Perl please be very descriptive, I am still somewhat new to using object oriented programming).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use one global hash as a replacement `my %G = (var1 => 1, var2 => 5, ..)`

Comment: You know that when you do `my $var1, $var2, $var3;`, that `my` only affects `$var1`. You need to use parentheses `my ($var1, $var2,...)`. If you have `use strict` enabled, it will catch such errors, and `use warnings` will let you know of them.

Comment: The next step is to introduce objects.

Comment: "Also if I use "{}" to scope variables what happens if sub1 and sub2 share variables that they don't want sub3 to have access to, and then I also want sub1 and sub3 to share variables that sub2 won't have access to?" -- you're in charge of your code--it doesn't have a life of its own, and for (say) sub2 to modify variables, *you have to write code that modifies those variables*.

Comment: @i alarmed alien Of course I know that I am in charge of my own code, but there are many situations where a script will be passed on to another programmer who may not fully understand how it operates (Or the original programmer may set it aside for months and come back to it).  Without much knowledge of how the script operates the programmer may inadvertently change the value of a global variable without realizing it.

Comment: If you passing any script to other programmers, here is time start using packages/objects... IMHO..

Comment: @tjwrona1992 that is where good documentation of the code is vital!

Comment: Documentation of the code is important, but writing code in ways that are robust is important too. One of the downsides of Perl OO (without modules) is that it's quite easy to tamper with the object attributes without going through the object interface - this encourages bad behaviour. 
Globals have the same inherent problem - make your subroutines homicidally possessive, and you will avert future grief.

Comment: @Sobrique I could pass 4 variables into a subrouting and return 4 variables from a subroutine just to ensure that they remain local, but how far is too far?  Passing and returning large amounts of variables from subroutines can very quickly make neat code look very ugly.  Using globals can keep the code neat, but then you have the issue of using globals which you are trying to avoid in the first place! its a lose/lose situation.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Ugly? Perhaps. Safe? Definitely. One way to make subroutine arguments slightly saner is passing hashrefs to allow named arguments, e.g. `answer({ name => 'Sir Lancelot of Camelot', quest => 'To seek the Holy Grail', favorite_color => 'blue' });` At some point, even this becomes unwieldy, and you need to use OO (with Moose or equivalent). I don't think OO is too heavyweight, even for many scripts. You'll be amazed how much cleaner your code becomes.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I think that, like recursion elimination, the best way to localise variables depends on the exact nature of the variables. Perhaps you could give us some insight into the sort of values you are sharing across all of your code?

Comment: If you've got a lot of parameters, pass by reference works too - you can take a locally scoped set of variables, pass the references in the sub call, and have the sub modify them. It's not ideal, because things are changing 'off screen' but at least you know it's happening, and you've given explicit permission for it.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Re. "I was wondering if there was an alternative to passing a bunch of variables around" Yes, it is OO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Why* you shouldn't use globals is covered pretty well in the comments and in [Sobrique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25788872/176646). I'd like to give a simple (contrived) example of *how* to avoid globals by using objects:

*Knight.pm*

```
package Knight;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has 'name' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1
);

has 'quest' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1
);

has 'favorite_color' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

*cross_bridge_of_death*

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use 5.010;

use Knight;
use List::Util qw(none);

sub cross_bridge {
    my ($crosser) = @_;

    my @answers = ($crosser->name, $crosser->quest, $crosser->favorite_color);
    my $success = none { /\. No / } @answers; # Can't change your answer

    return $success;
}

my $lancelot = Knight->new(
    name           => 'Sir Lancelot of Camelot',
    quest          => 'To seek the Holy Grail',
    favorite_color => 'Blue'
);

my $galahad = Knight->new(
    name           => 'Sir Galahad of Camelot',
    quest          => 'To seek the Holy Grail',
    favorite_color => 'Blue. No yel...'
);

foreach my $knight ($lancelot, $galahad) {
    say $knight->name, ': "Auuuuuuuugh!"' unless cross_bridge $knight;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Sir Galahad of Camelot: "Auuuuuuuugh!"
```

---

This example uses [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose), which is just one of several modules that improve on Perl's native OO syntax.

Now, this may seem like a lot of code just to check a few strings. After all, we could get rid of the `Knight` class altogether and change our `cross_bridge` function so that we could call it something like this:

```
cross_bridge($name, $quest, $favorite_color);
```

Or even:

```
cross_bridge({
    name           => $name,
    quest          => $quest,
    favorite_color => $favorite_color
});
```

But then we would have to keep track of three variables instead of one. Using an object allows us to access multiple attributes through a single variable, so you can reduce the number of arguments you're passing to subroutines.

OO is a big topic (I haven't even touched on methods, which can simplify your code even more). I would recommend reading [`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and then browsing through the [Moose manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual), starting with the section [Moose concepts](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Concepts). There are also several other popular alternatives to Moose listed in `perlootut`.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand why the edict is "thou shalt not use globals". It's because something of global scope can be modified anywhere in your program, and that can quite easily lead to bugs - e.g. a subroutine you don't expect tampers with something in a way you don't expect.

There's also an issue of 'namespace pollution' - if you globally define `$result`, what's supposed to happen if someone else uses that name?

This is why you should avoid globals as much as possible. It's quite easy to end up with bugs based on things that happen 'elsewhere' in code, that are working in ways you don't expect. If you create a self contained function, I shouldn't need to read it to figure out what's going on. Which means passing in parameters, and extracting returned results, and that being the only way data is moved around or changed.

This might seem onerous - and in that you'd be correct - but it's also really important, because it's significantly easier to track a bug that can only have come from a few lines of code, than one that might have come from anywhere in a 10,000 line program. If `sub` starts to break down, look to passing hashes or object oriented perl.

Comment: And I'd add - one of the key features of object oriented code is the encapsulation.